# Ethernet not working (neither even detected) on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: ethernet

Ethernet is not being detected on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04.1, My Desktop model is Dell OptiPlex 5040. Ethernet is not detected after completion of install tion and Network driver is also not available at Dell site for this model. How can i use network on this PC

## ifconfig

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1800 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:1800 (1.8 KB)
```

## lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   version: 31
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7100000-f711ffff
```

Comment: What output do you get when you type command `ifconfig` in terminal?

Comment: Can you run the command: `sudo lshw -C network` and see if it identify the network card? Can you put the output here please.